# If all the players were killed or resetting during a round, how do you stop the game and display a message for everybody?

Tags: lua, roblox

I am developing a remastered game, and want to figure how the round will stop if all players were killed or reset, and display a message for all players, "Game over", and returns back to the lobby intermission.

This is my main script for the game I am making. In the past, I've tried If statements in this script, however it didn't work and it ends up not displaying my another scripts as well.

```
local s = script.Stat

t = 0

while true do

    local plrs = game.Players:GetPlayers()

    t = 15  
    repeat
    t = t - 1
    s.Value = t.." seconds left"
    wait(1)

    if plrs == 0 then
        s.Value = "Alive: "..plrs
    end

    until t == 0

    s.Value = "Game over!"

    wait(5)

end
```

I expect the script to find all the players in a round that is killed, but the output seems to work only for the seconds remaining.

Answer (score 0):

If you add a listener to every player's [Humanoid.Died](https://developer.roblox.com/api-reference/event/Humanoid/Died) signal, you can keep track of which players die in a round.

In a Script, write something like this :

```
-- use a map of player names to keep track of who is still alive
local playersAlive = {}
local listenerTokens = {}
local SPAWN_LOCATION = CFrame.new()

-- make some helper functions
local function getCountPlayersAlive()
    local numPlayersAlive = 0
    for playerName, isAlive in pairs(playersAlive) do
        numPlayersAlive = numPlayersAlive + 1
    end

    return numPlayersAlive
end

local function beginRound()    
    -- get the list of all of the players in the round
    local allPlayers = game.Players:GetChildren()
    for _, player in ipairs(allPlayers) do

        -- find the associated Player in the workspace
        local character = game.Workspace:FindFirstChild(player.Name)
        if character then

            -- add an event listener for when they die
            local humanoid = character:FindFirstChildOfClass("Humanoid")
            local deathSignalToken = humanoid.Died:Connect(function()

                -- when this player dies, signal that there is one less player
                playersAlive[player.Name] = nil
            end)

            -- add the player to the list of players for this round
            playersAlive[player.Name] = true

            -- move the players into the game arena
            player.Character:SetPrimaryPartCFrame(SPAWN_LOCATION)

            -- disconnect this signal at the end of the round
            table.insert(listenerTokens, deathSignalToken)

        else
            -- could not find the player, make them sit out this round
        end
    end
end

local function endRound()
    -- clean up the game board, reload the players, do whatever you have to

    -- clean up any death signals from last round
    for _, token in ipairs(listenerTokens) do
        token:Disconnect()
    end
end


-- set up the game loop
local GAME_LENGTH = 30 -- seconds
local INTERMISSION_LENGTH = 15 -- seconds

spawn(function()
    while true do
        -- phase 1 - set up the round
        beginRound()

        -- phase 2 - play the round
        local gameTimer = GAME_LENGTH
        while gameTimer > 0 and getCountPlayersAlive() > 0 do
            local count = getCountPlayersAlive()
            print(string.format("Time Left : %d - Players Left : %d", gameTimer, count))
            wait(1)
            gameTimer = gameTimer - 1
        end

        -- phase 3 - celebrate winners and clean up the previous round
        endRound()

        -- phase 4 - intermission before the next round
        wait(INTERMISSION_LENGTH)
    end
end)
```

Sorry for the lengthy example, but I hope this helps.